# Replacing a value in all cells of a DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an example df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['100,100', '200,200'],
                   'B': ['200,100,100', '100']})

        A          B
0   100,100    200,100,100
1   200,200    100
```

and I want to replace the commas ',' with nothing (basically, remove them). You can probably guess a real-world application, as many data is written with thousand separators, feel free to introduce me to a better method.

Now I read the documentation for pd.replace() [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) and I tried several versions of code - it raises no error, but does not modify my data frame.

```
df = df.replace(',','')
df = df.replace({',': ''})
df = df.replace([','],'')
df = df.replace([','],[''])
```

I can get it working when specifying the column names and using the ".str.replace()" method for Series, but imagine having 20 columns. I also can get this working specifying columns in the df.replace() method but there must be a more convenient way for such an easy task. I could write a custom function, but pandas is such an amazing library it must be something I am missing.

This **works**:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace(',','')
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`df.replace`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) has a parameter `regex` set it to `True` for partial matches.

By default `regex` param is `False`. When `False` it replaces only **exact** or **fullmatches**.

From Pandas docs:

> str: string exactly matching to_replace will be replaced with the value.

```py
df.replace(',', '', regex=True)

        A          B
0  100100  200100100
1  200200        100
```

---

In [`pd.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) by default it's `regex` param is `True`.

From docs:

> Equivalent to [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) or [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20sub#re.sub), depending on the regex value.

Determines if assumes the passed-in pattern is a regular expression:

- If True, assumes the passed-in pattern is a regular expression.
- If False, treats the pattern as a literal string

Answer (score 2):

Though your immediate question has probably been answered, I wanted to mention that if you are reading this data in from a `csv` file, you can pass the `thousands` argument with a comma `","` to indicate that this should be treated as an integer and remove the comma:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

csv_file = io.StringIO("""
A,B,C
"1,000","2,000","3,000"
1,2,3
"50,000",50,5
""")

df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, thousands=",")

print(df)
       A     B     C
0   1000  2000  3000
1      1     2     3
2  50000    50     5

print(df.dtypes)
A    int64
B    int64
C    int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you, I assumed there was a more concise method!